# understanding socket.io async start / stop with promises

Tags: node.js, sockets, asynchronous, coffeescript, promise

I am adding socket-io broadcast capabilities to an application. I am using (bluebird) promises, and testing with mocha. I want to be able to start & stop server asynchronously (both for production start/stop and for test isolation), but I find that the documentation for the necessary callbacks / events is spotty. It also seems that some of the events aren't available at the top level of socket.io.

If anyone is familiar with this setup, I would be very grateful for their comments vs the following code. Am I going about this correctly? Am I missing something? In particular I wonder about how to provide proper error callbacks -- event/callback doc is quite unclear.

Server start and stop:

```
Promise = require 'bluebird'
_ = require 'lodash'

activityServer = null

start = ()->
  http = require('http')
  express = require('express')()
  server = http.createServer(express)
  io = require('socket.io')(server)
  new Promise (resolve, reject)->
    server.on 'listening', ->
      activityServer = io.attach(server)
        .of(ACTIVITY_NAMESPACE)
      resolve()
    server.listen(PORT)

disconnectAll = ()->
  Promise.map _.values(activityServer.server.nsps), (nsp)->
    new Promise (resolve, reject)->
      disconnecting = {}
      for id of nsp.connected
        disconnecting[id] = true
      if _.size(disconnecting) == 0
        resolve()
      else
        for id, socket of nsp.connected
          socket.on( 'disconnect', ((id)->
            ->
              delete disconnecting[id]
              if _.size(disconnecting) == 0
                resolve()
            )(id))
          socket.disconnect(true)
```

Test setup:

```
describe 'push activities', ->
  before ->
    server.start()

  after ->
    server.stop()

  client = null
  beforeEach ->
    client = connectClient()

  afterEach ->
    new Promise( (resolve, reject)->
      client.on( 'disconnect', ->
        console.log( 'closed client' )
        resolve() )
      client.on( 'error', (err)->
        reject(err)
      )
      client.close()
    ).then( ->
      server.disconnectAll()
    )
```

Comment: I don't know anything about socket.io, but I can spot a few promise antipatterns in your code: 1) That `activityServer` that is asynchronously created should rather be the `resolve(…)` value than a global variable. `disconnectAll` would then take this value as an argument. 2) Those `_.size(disconnecting)` calls are horrible. Rather create a single `new Promise` for the disconnect event of *each `.connected` socket*, and use `Promise.all` another time.

Comment: Bergi -- the activityServer is a global because in between start and stop it has to be used. re 2) -- your partly right; in fact there is only one promise per namespace but these could be combined. _.size(disconnecting) is just how I avoid creating a promise per socket. Better would be to simply count # of disconnect calls since I don't really care about ids, but I don't see how Promise.all() would come in.

Comment: btw -- in testing I had more luck calling attach with port rather than server. I'm not sure why. I can still listen to the underlying server at io.httpServer. Seems like a glitch in socket.io....

Comment: No, it should not be global but the result of the returned promise because it can only be used *after* start. And you would use `Promise.all` instead of manually counting, no need to avoid creating a promise per socket!

Comment: 1) it is global but "null" until initialized. The finally in stop also guarantees that is null after teardown. Is a singleton so don't see why it shouldn't have module scope. (probably I need to make sure start is idempotent)  2) -- ah "no need to avoid" sorry misunderstood. I thought this was a harmless optimization -- whether I count or bluebird counts doesn't really matter but can see why might be less than idiomatic. Is there another reason not to count besides being too low level?

Comment: Being low level typically means being more error-prone. Yours *seems* to be fine, but many people implementing `.all` forget the `==0` case or caring about errors. Also, "less idiomatic" is often "less DRY"